# thestone D:2 The Haystack nudges

Tags: the-stone

Can anybody provide me nudge / hint to solve D:2 "the haystack" in the stone? (http://www.scarecrowsfield.com/index.php?task=show&level=puzzle&group=1&left=D&right=2)?

I've looked at it for a long time but I haven't been able to come any closer to finding a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is rather... *circular*.

You might say it's... *in the sky*?

Hope these helped.  I had to dig out my ancient binder of Stone answer pages to figure out how to help you.  It's great to see that someone archived the puzzles, I'm going to have to go through them again, get to the ones I hadn't solved!

Comment: Well... I already solved it some time ago (since it was 2 months ago) but... thanks :) I have some other questions where I need nudging, I will post them here. It would be nice to have more thestone nudges I think. and I think you better remove the answer ... people won't like that even if it is behind a spoiler tag (i think)

Comment: p.s. yes that puzzle site is GREAT! I also have my history on the old site and when I found this free site... exactly like yourself I had to think again about all the ones I already solved. So yes I'm going trough them again also. It's insanely addictive though LOL! (I wrote about it in 2008: http://edward.de.leau.net/return-to-the-stone-now-free-supertip-20080510.html) and I guess not all the old stoners have returned :)

Comment: I remember that the community used to have your head if it was found that you had posted an answer, but I thought it might be okay to do that here.  I've removed it, as per your suggestion, however.

Comment: thanks! yes i think the community will still have your head lol